# How to get the logged in user id in javascript files in laravel

Tags: laravel, events, echo

I am following below link for event broadcasting in laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#concept-overview

but I do not understand how to get `${orderId}` in js file in below code.

```
Echo.private('order.${orderId}')
.listen('ShippingStatusUpdated', (e) = > {
    console.log(e.update);
});
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would more than likely have this stored on a component. The example above would probably be more specific to an orders page or an orders component where you (I would imagine at least) already have the id so you can listen for events that are specific to that order.

So, something like:

```
data() {
    return {
        order: {}
    };
},

mounted() {

    Echo.private('order.${this.order.id}')
            .listen('ShippingStatusUpdated', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
}
```

When you define your `Event` you specify the channel you channel you want it to be emitted on. If you don't want the channel to be specific to an `id` your just omit the id from the channel name in your `Event` and then do something like:

**PHP**

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('users');
}
```

**JS**

```
Echo.private('users')
        .listen('SomeEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
```

Hope
 this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ross Wilson, It is helpful.